# Event handlers not firing for completion of asynch call to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I recently managed to get a WCF service running in IIS. I created a simple console application to test this. I did click the option to generate the asynch calls, and when I create an instance of my service client, I have [FunctionName]Asynch methods and [FunctionName]Completed event handlers.

The problem is that the event handlers never fire. I set them up and put break points inside them. The break points never fire though. I know the initial asynch method is called, but no completion.

The service is in IIS and has been added to my project as a service reference.

Here's the code on the client side, although the problem is probably not there:

```
clt.SubmitEvalCompleted += (o, e) => {
            var sender = o as EvalServiceClient;

            Console.WriteLine("Submit completed");
            sender.GetEvalsAsync();
        };

        clt.GetEvalsCompleted += (o, e) => { 

            var listOfEvals = e.Result;

            foreach (var eval in listOfEvals)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Eval: " + eval.ID + " comments: " + eval.Comments);
            }
        };

        Eval evale = new Eval { Comments = "Comment", Submitter = "Me" };
        clt.SubmitEval( evale );
        clt.GetEvals();
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events will only be called if you call the asynchronous version of the method (SubmitEvalAsync, GetEvalsAsync). If you call the synchronous version, you'll get the result right away.